# long a = pow(10,1) returns 12, but as an int returns 10, why?

Tags: c, pow

I started programming a couple of weeks ago and now I am trying to solve a little bit more complicated(for me) task, which containce u.a. the function pow.

I found out that if I use a variable of type long and I want to make a progression of the type 10^n, where n++, the output of the variable by n=1 is somehow 12. For n=2 is logicaly 12^2=144, etc.

But if I change the variable to the type of int, then the output is as expected 10^1 and 10^2.

I know it has to do with the type and the length of the variable, but I cannot understand why exactly and why the functions changes then 10 to 12 and first then executes the calculation. Can someone explain me why ?

```
while  (n < 15)
    {    long a = pow(10,n);
         long b = pow(10, n - 1);
         printf("n= %i, a= %lo, b= %lo \n", n, a, b);
         n++;
    }
```

Where length is a variable.

The output is this:

> n= 1, a= 12, b= 1
>   n= 2, a= 144, b= 12
>   n= 3, a= 1750, b= 144
>   ...

Comment: Don't describe your code but show it. You can [edit] your question. Read this [mcve] and this [ask]

Comment: `long a = pow(10, 1); printf("a: %ld\n", a);` outputs `10` for me.

Comment: [man 3 pow](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html) and what type does `pow` return? Neither `int` or `long`.

Comment: I can't reproduce any of what you claim. Please [edit] and show your verbatim code and tell us on which platform your code is running and which compiler you use?

Comment: Could you by mistake displayed the output in base 8 ? like in `printf("%o", a);`

Comment: Be aware that the library function `pow` might not return the *exact* value, for example `pow(10, 3)` might return `999.99999` which when assigned to an integer type, is truncated to `999`.

Comment: You're printing octal numbers: Change `%lo` to `%d`. Read again the documentation of `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Format `%lo` outputs the `long int` number in octal, not decimal. Octal 12 is decimal 10.

Comment: Exactly! Also there's an imlicit conversion from `double` to `long int` which is not the problem.

Comment: @Maf It's not that obvious whether it is or is not a problem – the 14-th power of 10 is 47 digits long in binary. If `long int` is 32-bit, the conversion will fail.

Comment: Yes, you're right. One more point: wouldn't `float` be 32-bit if `long int` is 32-bit?

Comment: @Maf Three points: 1. Sizes needn't be correlated, but `float` probably _is_ 32-bits. 2. Even if `float` is 32 bits long, those bits are partitioned into mantissa and exponent, so the precision of `float` is less than 32 bits. 3. However,  `pow()` type is `double`, not `float`.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write `double`. Let me reformulate my question please:

Comment: Is `double` always 64-bit independently of the Operating System?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a single and double precision floating-point formats defined in the IEEE 754 standard as binary32 and binary64, respectively, were adopted as `float` and `double` in ANSI C.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `float` = 32-bits; `double`=64-bits. I'd upvote twice this answer if I could.

Comment: @Mafia That was a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: But I was talking about the short and clear answer as well.